# count the number of views of a post excluding own views

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, views

I am using  [WP Post Views](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postviews/) plugin to display the post number of views. To do so, I use:

```
<?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?>
```

This plugin gives 3 choises in its setting :

- Count Views From Everyone
- Count Views From Guests only
- Count Views From registered users only

My website is a private community of authors. I have created some badges that are awarded automatically if some conditions are met.

For example, I award a badge to an author when its post attain a certain number of views by the other members of the community. (I use `add_action( 'update_post_meta', 'award_badge'` on the meta field updated by `the_views();` )

**The problem** is: The plugin I am using can increment the number of a post views if the author himself see it. It will be good if the number of views increase only when other authors see the post.

I hope my explanation is clear enough. I thank you for your time.

**Questions:**
Is there a plugin that provides this feature of excluding its own post visits from views count?

Is there a piece of code that can be a starting point for me to create a post count views plugin?

You usual help is appreciated.

**Edit after S_Ha_Dum comment:**

The link to the code source is :http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-postviews/trunk/wp-postviews.php

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard to do but may require a plugin hack, which is discouraged. Can you post the _plugin_ code that manages counting/setting the views? Or provide a link to that code? Hopefully, there is a filter.

Comment: Ok dear @S_ha_dum, Can I post the code of the plugin as an edit? Or it will be better to give a link to the code?

Comment: The plugin has a trac. I have already found it. A link to that should be fine.

Comment: Totally agreeing with you, I give the link as an edit. Thank you very much for your help. Very hard for a beginner to find where to perform the hack. I am trying to understand this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin [appears to be processing the view on the `wp_head` hook.](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-postviews/trunk/wp-postviews.php#L48) That means you ought to be able to do something like this:

```
function remove_view_counter_wpse_102637() {
  global $post;
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

  if (
    is_single() 
    && !empty($current_user)
    && $post->post_author == $current_user->ID
  ) {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'process_postviews');
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'remove_view_counter_wpse_102637',1);
```

No guarantees. I don't use that plugin and can't test that, and the conditions may not be exactly right, but that concept should work.

Comment: Thank you very much dear @s_ha_dum, I will come back to give a feedback after implementing your idea. Thanks again

Comment: I believe the remove_action on the callback process_postviews is the solution. Unfortunatley it is still not working even if I changed get_currentuserinfo() (which doesnt work for me in previous operations) with $current_user= wp_get_current_user(); .. I will keep digging based on your idea

Comment: Perfectly working after changin '!=' by '=='. Thank you very much, you wrote the code, and I was inattentif reading it.

Comment: today I learned from you that there is a concept called : possibility to hack plugins. In the future I will be using remove_action. Thank you very much

Comment: Dear S_HA_DUM. How can I exclude also the duplicate views from same user during the same login session? How can I express is inside conditional if. Thank you very much . http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104324/prevent-multiple-counts-by-same-user-wp-postviews-plugin

Comment: @s_ha_dum : your code makes sense, but it does not work for me. How can I debug the problem? I checked that the `if` statement is true.. but still, the post view count increases upon every page load.